# storing file path in mysql database automatically

Tags: php, mysql

i was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction,

i have a large library of MP3 files, and i want to store them in a mysql database, also each album folder will have a artwork.png file, this also needs to be stored in the database for that album

file structure artist/album/track(s).mp3

i am trying to have it so that when i upload a new artist (folder), album (folder), or mp3 file to the server, it will automatically be added to the mysql db

i need "artist", "album", "artwork", "file_path" to be stored in the database

i would like to use php since that is what i am most familiar with

thanks for the help and suggestions!

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? You'll need to elaborate a bit more on that part. Also, are you accounting for different albums having the same name? You might be better off with a different folder structure that maps the name of the album to an ID.

Comment: @JohnP The album names won't be a problem, i have the the mysql database setup, i just don't know where to start from with the php

Comment: Will every uploaded .mp3 have all of the required information? I know after ripping some of my cd's the .mp3 files don't contain any info other than "Track #". You will have to account for situations such as this and have a way to mitigate built into the system as well unless you already know that every file WILL contain all of the desired information

Comment: Can you show the structure of your mysql tables?

Comment: Do you really want us to code a fully functional music library for you?

Comment: @Icefyre No, just looking to for some thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Php has a built in function to obtain the information stored in an mp3 ID3 tag. However as I mentioned in my comment above you will have to mitigate the situation where the information is not contained within the ID3 tag, unless of course you already know the information will always be in the tag.

[PHP API FOR id3_get_tag()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.id3-get-tag.php)

Answer (score 0):

If u store artist and album already u can build up your path anyway. I don't see the sense of storing the same information (such as artist/album/) twice.

Answer (score 0):

You should make 3 functions:

## 1:

Scan the dir where all artist folders are located (scandir with blacklisted ".." and "." should work)
For every folder launch function #2
Function header:

```
public function scanArtists(){
```

## 2

Scan the artist dir where this function was launched on (scandir with blacklist again)
For every album folder launch #3
Function header:

```
public function scanAlbum($artistName)
```

you should build the album path from artist name & album name
Save all albums to an album table with a mysql query (also save the artwork)

## 3

Scandir again. 
Now save all tracks to an tracks table with an foreign key pointing on the id of their album
Function header:

```
public function scanTracks($artistName, $albumName)
```